# ¿Qué hacer con preguntas MariaDB con etiquetas de MySQL?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

De un tiempo a esta parte, he notado que muchas preguntas que incluyen a [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) como su etiqueta, sin embargo las mismas preguntas contienen incluido la etiqueta de [phpmyadmin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) lo cual me indica que deben de tener instalado `xampp` o `wamp`.

Entonces en las últimas versiones de estos (xampp y wamp) los gestores de base de datos han sido cambiados de `mysql` a `maria DB` razón por la cual ahora saltan mensajes en `phpmyadmin` constantemente, como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y muchos otros, esta imagen pertenece a la pregunta: ["Un formulario en esta página tiene más de 10000 campos" ¿Qué puede suponer esto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227599/un-formulario-en-esta-p%C3%A1gina-tiene-m%C3%A1s-de-10000-campos-qu%C3%A9-puede-suponer-esto)

Entonces mis preguntas son:

- Al ser `Maria DB` un fork `MySql`, ¿no hay ningún problema en que la pregunta esté formulada con una etiqueta y no con la otra?
- ¿Cuándo se debe de editar la pregunta que al ser de `MariaDB` lleva la etiqueta [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)?
- En caso de no editar jamas las etiquetas, ¿no sería este como un "desprecio" o por lo menos "hacer de menos" a `MariaDB` a comparacion de `Mysql`?

No sé si me dejé entender, espero que sí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las preguntas orientadas a resolver dudas con la etiqueta `MySQL` pero que de fondo es sobre el uso de `MariaDB Server` se confunden por:

1. XAMPP el paquete para montar servidores web con Apache mas popular, inició y se mantuvo por mucho tiempo usando a `MySQL` como servidor de bases de datos
2. El uso de `MariaDB Server` hace sentir a los usuarios como si siguieran en ambiente de `MySQL` pues recordemos que partió como un *fork* del mismo
3. Salvo detalles como

   - JSON Functions
   - Engines para *HA* 
     Las demás características y funciones de *MySQL* son portables y funcionales a su contra parte *MariaDB*
4. Recordar también que por ejemplo el comando para acceder al servidor desde consola sigue siendo el mismo entre los 2 gestores `mysql -u root -p`
5. El OP que pregunte algo basado en el uso de MariaDB Server debe tener presente que

Una vez que inicias sesión en el `MariaDB Server` la CLI será similar a la siguiente

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 312
......
```

Donde el OP puede notar que esta en una versión que no es el famoso *MySQL*

Por otro lado tiene la opción de leer los detalles técnicos acerca de *XAMPP* donde se indica que servidor de bases de datos usa

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20181213.html)

1. Entonces es válido bajo una visión de que la herramienta parte de una que ya conocen
2. Salvo dudas de herramientas específicas de cada gestor, como ya se mencionó arriba, las demás funciones son en su mayoría genéricas
3. Se puede aportar en la edición la etiqueta correspondiente así como en la zona de comentarios un enlace a esta pregunta/respuesta para que sea aclarada la confusión